# Link in table row not showing well

Tags: javascript

```
let a = document.createElement('a');
let a1 = document.createElemnt('a');

let link = "www.link1.com/";
let link1 = "www.link2.com/";

a.setAtribute('href', link);
a1.setAtribute('href', link1);

a.inerHTML = "text1";
a1.inerHTML = "text2";

let match = a + ' ━ ' + a1;
```

This is my code. So I want to create two links with the teams that face each other like Text1 - Text2. And I want 'Text1' to be clickable so u get to their webiste.
I really don t undertand why it now shows "www.link1.com/ ━ [www.link2.com/"](http://www.link2.com/%22) in the table instead of "Text1 - Text2" being a link to the webistes.

Comment: Also The link is not clickable just shows as text The href

Comment: `let match = a + ' ━ ' + a1` I am afraid that is not the way how to append created DOM elements. Like this you merely concat its textcontents.

Comment: Thanks for your answere and Edit. But even if i only add one of the links like a it shows in this weird way

Comment: You either add it as a string using `innerHTML` or appned it as DOM using `appendChild`. Since it remains unclear from your example, which way you intend to take, we can not really help you out. Atleast add the funtionality of `insertR()`.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: I now edited for the example to make sense and I now explain the insertR method

Comment: Like I wrote above.. try to pass `"<a href = 'www.manutd.com'>manU</a>"` instead of `a`.

Comment: I get it to work with only one link now But how can I send a + string + a in a nice container? I was thinking about div/ul/span.?

Comment: Post the actual code of `insertR` and people might help you.

Comment: Okay @Lain though it would confuse but u are right it is needed I now show it.

Comment: THIS QUESTION IS HARD TO UNDERSTAND BUT I SOLVED IT THANKS EVERYONE

Comment: Unfortunately I can not delete

Answer (score 0):

your link URLs need to start with `http://` or `https://`